# Check if value exist, using Firebase realtime database and unity

Tags: c#, database, firebase, unity-game-engine

I'm working on unity3d project with firebase realtime database.
I'm stuck on how can I check if the Username already exists in the database, 
I wrote the code bellow but it always return TRUE even when the username doesn't exist.
Any ideas??

```
 void ExistingUser()
    {
        FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("Users").OrderByChild("username").EqualTo(username).GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;

            if(snapshot.Exists){
                DebugLog("Username exist"); 
            }

            else{
               // create new 
            }

        });
    }
```